# is it possible to have .any? method with two blocks?

Tags: ruby

I have this code to determinate the class returned:

```
def level_class(projects)
  return 'badge-danger' if projects.any?(&:suspicious_content?) || projects.any?(&:tiny_description?)
  'badge-info'
end
```

Is it possible to 'merge' `&:suspicious_content?` and `&:tiny_description?`?

That doesn't work but something like `projects.any?(&:suspicious_content? || &:tiny_description?)` would pretty cool!

Comment: No, not possible. You'll have to use the full block form

Comment: Ok thanks @SergioTulentsev ! I'm going to merge my `suspicious_content?` and `tiny_description?` methods, but I wanted to know if it's possible, in case I will have to do something like this in the future

Comment: It doesn't make sense. Block is not an object. You cannot do logic with blocks.

Comment: Your title does not seem to match what you wrote in the text.

Comment: @sawa makes sense if they don't know that these are blocks.

Answer (score 2):

"merge" does not make sense as the comments for your question have pointed out.  But you can achieve practically the same thing as your latter case like this:

```
projects.any?{ |i| i.suspicious_content? || i.tiny_description? }
```

Or, if you want to use a block multiple times, you can do as follows:

```
b = lambda{ |i| i.suspicious_content? || i.tiny_description? }
projects.any? &b
```

Comment: Thank you. It was a question by curiosity, I known that I could do it by this way but I was wondering if there was anything planned to do that with `&:`. Also, please excuse my english if it's not perfect and if I used the wrong word, english is not my first langage

Comment: @escanxr I have edited an answer to add another way.